# Difference between AC-1 and AC-3 algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, backtracking

I am trying to understand both algorithms but can't find the difference between them.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC-3_algorithm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that both algorithms have the same iterate-to-fixed-point structure. The difference is that AC-3 uses a data structure to avoid processing arcs whose endpoint domains haven't changed since the last time they were processed – such processing would accomplish nothing.

Answer (score 0):

AC-1 and AC-3 are two versions of Arc consistency. The version 1 (ac-1) has some problems such as re-revising stuff again and again and again. So, we can actually do a better algorithm to fix this problem which ac-3 does adding an accumulator variable which starts out empty. We kind of fill it up with the pairs that need to be revised once. And then, we have a while loop that kind of does controlled revisions. And the idea is that we basically start with any element u, v from this set.

Answer (score -1):

The difference is that AC-3 uses a queue to store arcs whereas AC-1 not.